# MYSQL Order By Sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with mysql order by, i have this query

```
SELECT
  videos_views.videos_views_id,
  videos_views.videos_views_date,
  SUM(IF(MONTH(videos_views.videos_views_date) = 2, videos_views.videos_views_total, 0)) AS total_view,
  videos.videos_id,
  videos.videos_title,
  videos.videos_description,
  videos.videos_author_list_id,
  author_list.author_list_name,
  author_list.author_list_id
FROM videos
  LEFT OUTER JOIN author_list
    ON videos.videos_author_list_id = author_list.author_list_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN videos_views
    ON videos.videos_id = videos_views.videos_views_id
WHERE author_list.author_list_video_type = 1
AND videos.videos_id >= 51108
GROUP BY videos_views.videos_views_id,
         videos.videos_id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN MONTH(videos_views.videos_views_date) = 2 THEN SUM(videos_views.videos_views_total) END DESC, 
  CASE WHEN MONTH(videos_views.videos_views_date) <> 2 THEN videos.videos_id END DESC
LIMIT 11
```

And it returns the following results

[image: First Query Returns Image]

If i use the first  order by  using DESC or ASC returns the same result above.

And i use the second order by using ASC returns the result bellow:

[image: Second Query Result image]

And I need the query to return the values in the following order bellow

[image: Result i need]

Please Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results suggest that you want:

```
order by total_views desc, videos_id desc
```

You can reference column aliases (safely) in the `order by`.